# Distance from layer's feature

Tags: qgis

I have 2 layers (.shp) point and polygon type. I want to create using QGIS a polygon layer or a raster around the layers' features in a fixed distance (500 meters). I found out how to make a raster around the point type layer but could not for the polygon type layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use 'fixed distance buffer' tool. You can find it in vector toolbox.

[image: Fixed distance buffer]

Using this tool you can create buffer for any shapefile and at any given distance you need.